# CFT with central charge different from 1 and 1/2?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, majorana-fermions

In $1+1$ dimensions, I know the $c=1$ $\rm CFT$ which describes a massless bosonic mode, and the $c=\frac{1}{2}$ $\rm CFT$, which describes a Majorana mode. Is it possible to write a Lagrangian corresponding to, say, a $c=\frac{1}{3}$ or $c=\frac{4}{3}$ $\rm CFT$ (or perhaps other fractions different from minimal models with $c=1-\frac{6}{m(m+1)})$? And what do we know about quasiparticle excitations there?

Comment: I guess that you are not  familiar with the $c<1$ minimal models.  If not  read the Big Yellow Book:  "Conformal Field Theory" by Philippe Francesco Pierre Mathieu  and David Senechal. There all is explained.

Comment: I am reading it, in which from the roots of the Kac determinant, one obtains c=1-\frac{6}{m(m+1)}. However, this does not seem to apply to c=1/3 or c=4/3. Or am I missing something?

Comment: $c=1-\frac{6}{m(m+1)}$ are the only possible values of the central charge between 0 and 1 corresponding to unitary theories. Above $c=1$, the situation is far less clear. There are of course examples of theories with fractional values of $c>1$ which are known (e.g. tensor products of minimal models), but we have almost no sense for what the full landscape of theories looks like.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. For tensor products of minimal models, we have direct sums of cental charges and thus c=4/3 is not in that group. Are there any insights into this c=4/3 theory?

Comment: @danport There are some CFTs with $c=4/3$ listed here https://www.math.ksu.edu/~gerald/voas/voa/centralcharge.html and here https://www.math.ksu.edu/~gerald/voas/mtc/mtc-bycc.html

Comment: @Ruben Verresen These are helpful websites. Thank you.